# What are the differences between mobiledata and cloudant services?

Tags: cloudant, ibm-cloud

hello I am analyzing these two services to use In my app, and I could not find some doc about the difference between these two services. I know that mobiledata extends the cloudant, but what are the pro and cons? In my case I need to have more control above the data, for example create views (I could not create In mobiledata service) etc

So, do you know what the main divergences between these two services? When to use mobile data or cloudant?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to use Cloudant on Bluemix from an iOS application:

1. Use Cloudant directly by adding it as a service to your application.
2. Use [MobileFirst for iOS](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/mobilefirst/index.html), the [Data](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/data/index.html#data) part specifically (currently beta).
3. Use the [Mobile Data](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/mobiledata/index.html#gettingstarted) cross-platform SDK.

(1) and (2) allow you to use views within Cloudant by adding them 
via either the Cloudant dashboard or by using the Cloudant HTTP API.

(3) is a service which uses Cloudant in the background, but provides
no direct access to your data using the Cloudant HTTP API; you're 
limited to the services exposed by the SDK. Therefore you can't use 
many Cloudant features like views or Cloudant Query. Think of 
Cloudant more as an implementation detail here, rather than an 
exposed component as it is for (1) and (2).

Therefore, (1) or (2) is probably more suitable for your needs as 
you mention wanting to use views.

Answer (score 0):

Backend of mobile data service of bluemix is cloudant.For details please refer below link on getting started:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-rapiddev-app/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/managing-your-databases-in-the-cloud-how-cloudant-does-it/

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-rapiddev-app/

P.S- Cloudant is no-sql(create view wont be supported) DBAAS

For details on no-sql,please follow below link:

http://www.zdnet.com/article/what-is-nosql-and-why-do-you-need-it/

Comment: Hello aka hay, just to note, views in couchdb are mapreduce results visualization

Comment: i mean to say sql's ddl,dml wont b supported

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant is the IBM bluemix mobile data backend. And yes you can build sorted secondary key:value indexes, called "views" using JavaScript MapReduce functions.

Here is an example  :

```
map: function(doc){
    if (doc.rep){ emit({"rep": doc.rep}, doc.amount); }
}
reduce: _sum
```

For more details you can refer these links :

- http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html
- http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html#basic
- http://examples.cloudant.com/whatwouldbiebersay/_design/whatwouldbiebersay/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For mobiledata cloudant is acting behind the scenes. Cloudant is an open source

non-relational, distributed database service of the same name that requires zero-configuration.

Cloudant is based on the Apache-backed CouchDB project and the open source BigCouch

project.

Please follow below link for more details:

https://cloudant.com/cloudant-ibm-bluemix-tutorials-and-demos/